# Where can I find the Watson Assistant ID for invoking requests?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

[The documentation for Watson Assistant v2](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2?code=node#create-a-session) dryly mentions that the parameter for `assistant_id` can be easily found:

> Unique identifier of the assistant. You can find the assistant ID of an assistant on the Assistants tab of the Watson Assistant tool.

I've looked high and low, and haven't found anything but the Skill ID and Workspace ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IBM Watson Assistant console is rather confusing to use. I've found it a good lesson to sort of explore all the screens as most of the information can be found somewhere; it's just a matter of finding where.

The Assistant ID can be found from the right-most "Assistants" tab. Do *not* click on the assistant itself (which might make sense, as from there you find the API details), but from the *overview* of Assistants, click on the three dots next to the assistant you'd like to see the ID of:

[image: Assistant list]

From there, click on the "API details" from the left, where the Assistant ID is displayed:

[image: Assistant settings]

Yes, it's very unintuitive that this information is offered under Assistant Settings.